# What are good coding editors that can run without a GPU?

Tags: 16.04, programming, text-editor, x11-forwarding

I have a VM with Ubuntu, which I use mainly for testing code written with my usual tools in Windows. I connect to the VM with ssh and use X11 forwarding.

I'm used to VS Code and Sublime Text, but as the VM setup does not provide it a GPU I quickly found that this makes both render pretty slowly, with big lags even for scrolling through code. I've considered X11 forwarding being the problem, but other programs like nautilus don't show the lags.

So what are my options for an editor that runs well with just the CPU for rendering itself?

Comment: What is good for me is bad to you. Nothing wrong with vi/vim/sed/nano. I am a server user ;-) I would fix the problem, the lag. Maybe power them VM up a bit more?

Comment: `GVim` should work flawlessly.